# How active a class in angular when do click in <li> element

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

```
<ul>
  <li ng-click="catalog.selected = ''">ALL</li>
  <li ng-click="catalog.selected = 'uno'">UC</li>
  <li ng-click="catalog.selected = 'dos'">CEM</li>
  <li ng-click="catalog.selected = 'cuatro'">SMB</li>
  <li ng-click="catalog.selected = 'cinco'">OTHER</li>
</ul>
```

How active any class when do click in

and desactivate when click in other

(like a menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-class` and set the condition:

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : catalog.selected == ''}" ng-click="catalog.selected = ''">ALL</li>
<li ng-class="{'active' : catalog.selected == 'uno'}" ng-click="catalog.selected = 'uno'">UC</li>
<li ng-class="{'active' : catalog.selected == 'dos'}" ng-click="catalog.selected = 'dos'">CEM</li>
<li ng-class="{'active' : catalog.selected == 'cuatro'}" ng-click="catalog.selected = 'cuatro'">SMB</li>
<li ng-class="{'active' : catalog.selected == 'cinco'}" ng-click="catalog.selected = 'cinco'">OTHER</li>
```

Comment: Ok, this is great... but how asign a init class to a <li ng-click="catalog.selected = ''">ALL</li> (when refresh the website class active default in the first <li>) I tryed with ng-init but does't work ... thanks

Comment: `ng-init="catalog.selected = ''"` @Gerard